# When restarting the cnosdb database, panic occurred,How is this going？

Tags: database, rust, time-series, cnosdb

When restarting the cnosdb database, panic occurred,How is this going？I restart the database as follow:

```
# start CnosDB
cargo run -- run --deployment-mode singleton --config ./config/config_8902.toml

# run test
cargo run --package test

# kill CnosDB after completing the test

# restart CnosDB
cargo run -- run --deployment-mode singleton --config ./config/config_8902.toml
```

and after restart the cnosdb, panic occurred

I check the log as follow ,

```
2023-08-30T10:16:12.453348000+08:00  INFO tskv::kvcore: Recover: delete table, tenant: cnosdb, database: public, table: test
2023-08-30T10:16:12.453394000+08:00  INFO tskv::kvcore: Drop table: deleting 8 columns in table: cnosdb.public.test
2023-08-30T10:16:12.453726000+08:00  INFO tskv::kvcore: Drop table: vnode 24 deleting 40 fields in table: cnosdb.public.test
2023-08-30T10:16:12.453757000+08:00  INFO tskv::kvcore: Drop table: vnode 21 deleting 8 fields in table: cnosdb.public.test
2023-08-30T10:16:12.453905000+08:00 ERROR tskv::memcache: column fa not found in schema
2023-08-30T10:16:12.453919000+08:00 ERROR tskv::memcache: column fb not found in schema
The application panicked (crashed).
Message:  called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: InvalidPoint
Location: /Users/yukkit/VCWorkspace/cnosdb/tskv/src/kvcore.rs:230

Backtrace omitted. Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display it.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.
```

I don't know what is "InvalidPoint",